# How to insert json data to sqflite table without clicking anything in app(Something like at first init of the app)

Tags: json, flutter, insert, sqflite, favorites

Can you help me with inserting ready json data that is stored in assets file to sqflite table.
And for example my json file

```
[
  {
    "word": "json",
    "value": "format that uses human-readable text to store and transmit data "
  },
  {
    "word": "life",
    "value": "a gift"
  },
  {
    "word": "work",
    "value": "money"
  }
]
```

and also at inserting that data to table, sqflite should add an another string for each key-value containing something like "inFavorite": "false".

so I've seen a lot of videos doing that in app, but not one that insert ready data to sqflite.
I would be grateful if you could help me!

Is that possible?

Thank you for your help!

I tried a lot of things but there is no result

Comment: you can do main method or on MaterialApp level widget initState

Comment: Hi! thanks for answer. I know that i need to do that at initstate, but the question is how should look that method and how i can access to assets path with json file and get that data inserted to sqflite table. Can you share an example?